# Local Truncation error

Tags: numerical-methods

We have error formulas for Gaussian Quadrature and polynomial interpolation with 10 Gaussian points, use them to derive formulas for the local truncation error, where $$P = \frac{f^n(\xi)}{n!}\prod_{i=0}^{n}(t-t_i)$$ is the error for Polynomial interpolation, 
and error of Gaussian Quadrature: 
$$Q = \frac{(b-a)^{2n+1}(n!)^4}{(2n+1)![(2n)!]^3}$$
How can I derive the formula for local error truncation using error formula above?

Comment: Gaussian quadrature is not an interpolation method, so these don't really have anything to do with each other. So I'm not sure how we could help you here. I also do not really understand your question anyway. To analyze Gaussian quadrature, the best approach I know of is to estimate the minimal degree $n$ of a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\varepsilon/(2(b-a))$ for all $x$. Then I can prove that it is enough to use $(n+1)/2$ nodes to estimate the integral to within $\varepsilon$.

Comment: oh, I should be more clear in this. We have error formulas for Gaussian Quadrature and polynomial interpolation with 10 Gaussian points, use them to derive formulas for the local truncation error.

Comment: I edited my post. Sorry for the lack of information cause the misunderstanding my question.

Comment: The local truncation error for what method and for what problem?

Comment: To my understanding, the local truncation error between them. And, that is the full information of my question.

Comment: I still don't understand. Are you talking about the difference between the interpolatory quadrature rule at the Gaussian quadrature nodes and the actual Gaussian quadrature rule?

Comment: The requirement of my problem is you have to derive local truncation error with those error formulas

Answer (score -1):

Are you in Math 128B with Professor Strain?

If I'm not mistaken, I think this is the problem he's trying to solve:
https://math.berkeley.edu/~strain/128b.S15/p10.pdf

Here are some notes on the spectral integration method that must be used:
https://math.berkeley.edu/~strain/128b.S15/bvp.pdf

Some thoughts in the right direction: You're integrating over $[a, a + Ih]$ and $[a + (I+1)h, b]$ using Gaussian Quadrature, so you know the error for that exactly. How do you find the error of the spectral integration method that works over $[a + Ih, s_{Im + i}]$?

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: My mistake. Posted in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, I am in his class. I did in that way, but I am unsure if it's right or not? But at lease, I know I am in the right way.